# How do I update records in a loop in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a student portal in Laravel 8. I would love to update the class subjects.

Here is my controller

```php
public function UpdateAssignSubject(Request $request, $class_id)
{
    if ($request->subject_id == null) {

        $notification = [
            'message' => 'Sorry You did not Select any Subject',
            'alert-type' => 'error'
        ];

        return redirect()->route('assign.subject.edit', $class_id)->with($notification);

    } else {

        $countClass = count($request->subject_id);
        AssignSubject::where('class_id', $class_id)->delete();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $countClass; $i++) {
            $assign_subject = new AssignSubject();
            $assign_subject->class_id = $request->class_id;
            $assign_subject->subject_id = $request->subject_id[$i];
            $assign_subject->full_mark = $request->full_mark[$i];
            $assign_subject->pass_mark = $request->pass_mark[$i];
            $assign_subject->subjective_mark = $request->subjective_mark[$i];
            $assign_subject->save();

        } // End For Loop    

    }// end Else

    $notification = [
        'message' => 'Assigned Subject Updated Successfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    ];
}
```

This very piece of code *AssignSubject::where('class_id', $class_id)->delete();* is giving me issues since I am using the AssignSubject as a pivot table thus deleting the Id's produces errors in the long run.

Here is my view

```
    @foreach($subjects as $subject)
        <option value="{{ $subject->id }}" {{ ($edit->subject_id == $subject->id)? "selected": ""  
      }}>{{ $subject->name }}</option>
        @endforeach 
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <h5 style="color:black">Full Mark <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
        <div class="controls">
     <input type="text" name="full_mark[]" value="{{ $edit->full_mark }}" class="form-control" 
    style="background-color: rgb(176, 172, 216);color:black" > 
      </div>    
    <div class="col-md-2">          
      <div class="form-group">
        <h5 style="color:black">Pass Mark <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
        <div class="controls">
     <input type="text" name="pass_mark[]" value="{{ $edit->pass_mark }}" class="form-control" 
   style="background-color: rgb(176, 172, 216);color:black"> 
      </div>         
    </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">          
      <div class="form-group">
        <h5 style="color:black">Subjective Mark <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
        <div class="controls">
     <input type="text" name="subjective_mark[]" value="{{ $edit->subjective_mark }}" class="form- 
      control" style="background-color: rgb(176, 172, 216);color:black"> 
      </div>         
    </div>
        </div>
```

Please how can I update the record without deleting first. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the combination of `class_id` and `subject_id` unique?

Comment: class_id is from the class table why subject_id is from the subjects table. The programmed is developed in a manner that all subjects have to be entered first. Then the user selects from the subjects and assign to a particular class. HOWEVER a subject cannot appear twice in a class. so I would say  YES IT IS UNIQUE

Comment: Since the combination is unique, you can just pick the subject which needs to be updated inside the for loop (`$assign_subject = AssignSubject::where('class_id',$class_id)->where('subject_id', $request->subject_id[$i])->first()`), update all columns you need (e.g. `$assign_subject->full_mark = $request->fullmark[$i]`) and save your changes with `$assign_subject->save()`
However, if the `subject_id` is not yet assigned to the class, a new instance of `AssignSubject` needs to be created instead of picking it

Comment: Thank you for your response. The update is basically to add a new subject to the class. And I want to do this without deleting the previous Id's that have already been added. Since the model makes use of these id's. Is there a way  I can do this Sir.

Comment: have you tried attaching the newly generated ids?

Comment: Thank you Ramanath. The subject_id is used both for the marks and results. That means there are interwoven in the program. so I would not love have them changed. I am looking for a way of adding a new subject to a class after other subjects have been added without deleting the other existing subjects that is without creating a new instance of AssignSubject. Thank you once more for your efforts everyone

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the relationships, but I think what you're actually looking for is the `sync()` method. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting all entities, you can simply update them if they do exist.
In case they do not, you need to create a new one, like you did in your for loop.

I adjusted your code, to check if a subject already exists, if it does it updates it, otherwise a new one is created

```php
$countClass = count($request->subject_id);

// remove this line
// AssignSubject::where('class_id', $class_id)->delete();

for ($i = 0; $i < $countClass; $i++) {
    // a class can only have each subject 1 time, so you can filter for it
    $entity = AssignSubject::where('class_id', $class_id)
        ->where('subject_id', $request->subject_id[$i])
        ->first();
    
    // if entry does not exist, ->first() will return null, in this case, create a new entity
    $assign_subject = $entity ?? new AssignSubject();
    
    // update columns
    $assign_subject->class_id = $request->class_id;
    $assign_subject->subject_id = $request->subject_id[$i];
    $assign_subject->full_mark = $request->full_mark[$i];
    $assign_subject->pass_mark = $request->pass_mark[$i];
    $assign_subject->subjective_mark = $request->subjective_mark[$i];
    
    // save changes
    $assign_subject->save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you So Much. Your answer got the job done. I deeply appreciate